# $('input[name=nameofinput]:checked').val()'s value undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to send the value of an input to another page.

```
    $( this ).attr( "href", '?module=module_progress_report&Subject='+ $('input[name=subject]:checked').val()+ '&Centre_Selected_ID='+ encodeURIComponent($( this ).attr('data-centre')) + '&Class_Selected_Year='+ encodeURIComponent($( this ).attr('data-year')) + '&Class_Selected_All='+ encodeURIComponent($( this ).attr('data-all-centre')) +'&StartDate='+$('#report_date_start').val()+'&EndDate=18/12/2016');
```

Here,

```
$('input[name=subject]:checked').val()
```

This always returns undefined. The value is not getting selected. If I select one of the selection as default, then its value gets stored. What do I need to do?

### Edit

Here is the PHP and HTML:

```
<form class="small-box-footer" style="text-align:left;padding:10px;"  method="post" name="nameHere">

                              <?php
                              $query = "SELECT * FROM subject";
                            //$query="SELECT * FROM $base_name";
                            $result = mysql_query($query);
                            while ($row39 = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                                $Referrer_ID = $row39['Subject_ID'];
                                $Referrer_Name = $row39['Subject_Name'];      
                                ?>

<input type="checkbox" class="subject-selected" name="subject" value="<?=$Referrer_ID?>"> <?=$Referrer_Name?><?=$Referrer_ID?><br />

<?php } ?>

</form>
```

Below is the HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="subject-selected" name="subject" value="2"> GCSE Maths2<br />

                                                         <!--<a href="#" class="small-box-footer" data-id="<?php=$Referrer_Name?>" data-subject="GCSE English"   data-report-range="month">
                                      <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                                    </a>  
                                    -->
                                <input type="checkbox" class="subject-selected" name="subject" value="3"> GCSE English3<br />

                                                         <!--<a href="#" class="small-box-footer" data-id="<?php=$Referrer_Name?>" data-subject="GCSE Science"   data-report-range="month">
                                      <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                                    </a>  
                                    -->
                                <input type="checkbox" class="subject-selected" name="subject" value="4"> GCSE Science4<br />

                                                         <!--<a href="#" class="small-box-footer" data-id="<?php=$Referrer_Name?>" data-subject="GCSE Art"   data-report-range="month">
                                      <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                                    </a>  
                                    -->
                                <input type="checkbox" class="subject-selected" name="subject" value="5"> GCSE Art5<br />

                                                         <!--<a href="#" class="small-box-footer" data-id="<?php=$Referrer_Name?>" data-subject="GCSE Sociology"   data-report-range="month">
                                      <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                                    </a>  
                                    -->
                                <input type="checkbox" class="subject-selected" name="subject" value="6"> GCSE Sociology6<br />

                                                         <!--<a href="#" class="small-box-footer" data-id="<?php=$Referrer_Name?>" data-subject="OCR Nationals ICT"   data-report-range="month">
                                      <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                                    </a>  
                                    -->
                                <input type="checkbox" class="subject-selected" name="subject" value="8"> OCR Nationals ICT8<br />

                                                         <!--<a href="#" class="small-box-footer" data-id="<?php=$Referrer_Name?>" data-subject="OCR Nationals Sports"   data-report-range="month">
                                      <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                                    </a>  
                                    -->
                                <input type="checkbox" class="subject-selected" name="subject" value="9"> OCR Nationals Sports9<br />

                                                         <!--<a href="#" class="small-box-footer" data-id="<?php=$Referrer_Name?>" data-subject="OCR Nationals Business Studies"   data-report-range="month">
                                      <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                                    </a>  
                                    -->
                                <input type="checkbox" class="subject-selected" name="subject" value="10"> OCR Nationals Business Studies10<br />

                                                         <!--<a href="#" class="small-box-footer" data-id="<?php=$Referrer_Name?>" data-subject="Entry Science"   data-report-range="month">
                                      <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                                    </a>  
                                    -->
                                <input type="checkbox" class="subject-selected" name="subject" value="11"> Entry Science11<br />

                                                         <!--<a href="#" class="small-box-footer" data-id="<?php=$Referrer_Name?>" data-subject="Functional Skills English"   data-report-range="month">
                                      <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                                    </a>  
                                    -->
                                <input type="checkbox" class="subject-selected" name="subject" value="12"> Functional Skills English12<br />

                                                         <!--<a href="#" class="small-box-footer" data-id="<?php=$Referrer_Name?>" data-subject="Functional Skills Maths"   data-report-range="month">
                                      <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                                    </a>  
                                    -->
                                <input type="checkbox" class="subject-selected" name="subject" value="13"> Functional Skills Maths13<br />

                                                         <!--<a href="#" class="small-box-footer" data-id="<?php=$Referrer_Name?>" data-subject="ESOL"   data-report-range="month">
                                      <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                                    </a>  
                                    -->
                                <input type="checkbox" class="subject-selected" name="subject" value="14"> ESOL14<br />

                                                         <!--<a href="#" class="small-box-footer" data-id="<?php=$Referrer_Name?>" data-subject="Preparation for Working Life"   data-report-range="month">
                                      <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                                    </a>  
                                    -->
                                <input type="checkbox" class="subject-selected" name="subject" value="15"> Preparation for Working Life15<br />
```

Comment: What exactly returns `undefined`

Comment: May be `[name="subject"]` depends on `jQuery` version...

Comment: @Rayon is says that it's added in [version 1.0](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)?

Comment: Can you show the rendered html rather than php? For all I know your php is spitting out illegal html.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: The problem is that they are called the same.

Comment: What are called the same?

Comment: All input fields have the same `name` attribute.

Comment: @meskobalazs: I have added:selected to check which one it is.

Comment: But there could be more than one... Otherwise why would you not use radio buttons?

Comment: make sure you have at least onc is checked.

Answer (score 1):

try to run the same code `$('input[name=subject]:checked').val()` on console and see it what gives.

for `:checked` # make sure you've input element with type `checkbox`

you may also use this:

```
$('input[name="input_name"]').is('checked'); // will return true/false
```

Comment: I tried using this  if `($('input.checkbox_check').is(':checked'))
   alert($('input[name=subject]:checked').val());` but it never ran.

Comment: @FahadUddin - Is there any error in browser console ?

Comment: Also I think it should be $('input.subject-selected').is(':checked')

Comment: @I updated my code. No error in the browser console.

Comment: first of all, i want to tell you that `$('input[name=subject]:checked').val()` won't result you string text of the label it will return you first element value. see the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/xrv3x48e/1/

Comment: what do you want the result to be?

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `checked` with `selected`:

```
$('input[name=subject]:selected').val()
```

Comment: depends if it is a `<select>` element or `<input type="checkbox">`, in which case `:checked` is correct

Answer (score -1):

```
 Syntax: $( "input[value='name']" )
 try this 
 $('input[name="subject"]:checked').val()
```

Comment: Downvoted, because it does not matter, both syntax is just fine.

Comment: @Rayon possibly, but as this appears not to have changed since version 1.0, I think it unlikely. A blanket "depends on jQ version" answer to everything isn't particularly useful

Comment: @meskobalazs i think you need to refer https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/ once

Comment: quotes are important

Comment: @sams often yes, but as the docs state "value: An attribute value. Can be either a __valid identifier__ or a quoted string.", so in this case, no

Comment: @sams I did read it, just as I did read this: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors